# AngularJS compile and render HTML code from file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

There is the following code of my custom directive:

```
angular.module('app.directives', []).directive('userHeader', ['authService', '$compile', function(authService, $compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AEC',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var html;
        if (authService.currentUser()) {
          html = $compile("<h1>You successfully entered, dear {{ user.name }}!</h1>")(scope);
          elem.replaceWith(html);
        } else {
          html = $compile("<h1>You didn't enter</h1>")(scope);
          elem.replaceWith(html);
        }

        return scope.user = authService.currentUser();
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

So,as you can see, I render some HTML code using condition. But it's example, in my real application HTML code is much bigger, and I want to move HTML code from directive to template. But how can I compile  HTML code from template in this case? Thanks in advance

Comment: You know that you don't have to compile manually, do you?

Comment: Yes, because the code is big, and I don't want to store template code in directive

Comment: I mean you don't have to call `$compile` yourself, even in your example. That's what the `template` property is for. Consequently you can use `templateUrl` to fetch HTML from the server.

Comment: @zeroflagL Why don't you write that as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

A directive definition object can have a `template` or a `templateUrl` property. Both can be either a `String` or a `function` that returns a `String`. If you define `templateUrl` then the template is fetched from the server (or the template cache). That's what you seem to want.

```
angular.module('app.directives', []).directive('userHeader', ['authService', '$compile',      function(authService, $compile) {
 var loggedInUrl = '...';
 var notLoggedInUrl = '...';

 return {
   restrict: 'AEC',
     templateUrl: function() {
       if (authService.currentUser()) {
         return loggedInUrl;
       } else {
         return notLoggedInUrl;
       }
     }, 
     replace: true,
     link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
       scope.user = authService.currentUser();
     }
   };
 }

]);
```

When there is a current user then the template is fetched, compiled and replaces the element. There is nothing else to do.

Note that I used `replace: true`, which does almost the same as `element.replaceWith`. It's deprecated but won't be removed until Angular 2.0.